# Python Spilt function giving "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Tags: python

I have a file with below details and trying to spilt after equal sign

```
token='RFRQLUFVVE8tSUNFOmdHdXBPcWxUU0lUNWpmZ0Q5cGk1ZllqVXk0aUFTN3g3S040asasEE='
version='DTP.6.8.353.0.LIVE-17'

ice = {}
with open("file_name") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.split("=")
        ice[name] = value
```

I think due to second occurence of `'='` in token, it is throwing too many value to unpack

I want to keep output from token as it is. Is any other way to do it?

Comment: What does a `line` look like? Maybe you just want to do a `maxsplit`, like [`line.split("-", maxsplit=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: In addition to wkl comment, since `line` is  from a file you should also use rstrip to remove '\n' at end of each line, so would have `name, value = line.rstrip().split("=", maxsplit=1)`

Comment: It worked with maxspilt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want.

Using this, `value` will end at the first `=` is comes across:

```py
name, value, *_ = line.split("=")
```

And using this will mean `value` will potentially include an `=`:

```py
name, value = line.split("=", maxsplit=1)
```

Comment: It worked with maxspilt